# JavaScript map & find at the same time: findMap?

Tags: javascript, lazy-evaluation

How would you rewrite this without using a for loop?

```
const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => 2 * n;

let result;

// Find the first number 
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const r = expensiveFunction(a[i]);

    if (r > 100) {
        result = r;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

My naive approach:

```
const result = a.map(expensiveFunction).find(x => x > 100);
console.log(result);
```

But this runs `expensiveFunction` on all the elements, which I would like to avoid. In the above case, we should avoid running `expensiveFunction(4)`.

Some languages have `find_map` (e.g, [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map)), I didn't find it in lodash nor in underscore.

Comment: `a.find(x => expensiveFunction(x) > 100)` ?

Comment: No, see line `result = r;`. I want to return the expensiveFunction of that value.

Comment: right, my bad. Posted below.

Comment: The traditional functional way to handle this is to have "lazy" map which you can combine with a find operation. Without laziness we need to make a custom higher level function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Built-in `map` is greedy so you have to write your own, lazy version:

```js
const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => {
     console.log('expensiveFunction for', n); 
     return 2 * n 
};


function *map(a, fn) {
    for(let x of a)
        yield fn(x);
}

function find(a, fn) {
    for(let x of a)
        if (fn(x))
            return x;
}



r = find(map(a, expensiveFunction), x => x > 100)
console.log('result', r)
```

Unlike the stock `map`, this `map` is a generator and returns (yields) results on demand rather than processing the whole array at once. `find` and `map` in this example are "coroutines" and play some kind of a ping-pong game where `find` asks for results and `map` delivers them when asked. As soon as `find` is satisfied with what it's got, it quits and so does `map`, because nobody is asking for its results anymore.

You can also add `map`, `find` and friends to the `IteratorPrototype` to make them available for all iterators and be able to use dot notation:

```js
const IteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([][Symbol.iterator]()));

Object.defineProperties(IteratorPrototype, {
    map: {
        value: function* (fn) {
            for (let x of this) {
                yield fn(x);
            }
        },
        enumerable: false
    },

    find: {
        value: function (fn) {
            for (let x of this) {
                if (fn(x))
                    return x;
            }
        },
        enumerable: false
    },

});

//

const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => {
    console.log('expensiveFunction', n);
    return 2 * n
};


let r = a.values().map(expensiveFunction).find(x => x > 100);

console.log(r)
```

Here's a small library based on this technique: https://github.com/gebrkn/armita

---

### TypeScript Implementation and Tests

#### `find-map.ts`

```
function* map<T, U>(a: T[], fn: (x: T) => U) {
  for (let x of a) yield fn(x);
}

function find<T>(a: Generator<T, void, unknown>, fn: (x: T) => boolean) {
  for (let x of a) if (fn(x)) return x;
}

export function mapFind<T, U>(
  collection: T[],
  mapper: (item: T) => U,
  finder: (item: U) => boolean
): U | undefined {
  const mapperGenerator = map(collection, mapper);

  return find(mapperGenerator, finder);
}
```

#### `map-find.spec.ts`

**Note**: these tests utilize Bun, but shouldn't be far off from Jest.

```
import { describe, expect, it, mock } from "bun:test";
import { mapFind } from "./map-find";

describe("findMap", () => {
  const collection = [2, 5, 78, 4];
  const expensiveFunction = mock((n: number) => {
    console.log("expensiveFunction for", n);
    return 2 * n + ""; // Wanting to test with the change of types
  });
  const condition = (x: string) => x.length > 2;
  const result = mapFind(collection, expensiveFunction, condition);

  it("only calls the expensive function 3 times", () => {
    expect(expensiveFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });

  it("returns the expected result", () => {
    expect(result).toEqual("156");
  });
});
```

Comment: My favorite answer for now.

Comment: so much knowledge is flowing here, +1 :)

Comment: @FZs yeah. I was still waiting for other propositions.

Comment: @CodeManiac: added some explanations

Comment: @georg thanks for awesome explanation, that clarified a lot :)

Comment: Added TypeScript implementation to the wiki. The generics were driving me nuts for a while, but now everything checks out 

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```js
const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => 2 * n;
let findMap = arr => {
  let found = arr.find(a => expensiveFunction(a) > 100)
  return found !== undefined ? expensiveFunction(found) : found
}

console.log(findMap(a));
```

---

Alert:- JUST out of curiosity , But hacky or you can call it misuse of `find`

```js
const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => 2 * n;
let findMap = arr => {
  let returnValue;
  let found = arr.find(a => {
    returnValue = expensiveFunction(a)
    return returnValue > 100
  })
  return returnValue
}

console.log(findMap(a));
```

Comment: No, the final result should be `expensiveFunction(78)`, i.e. `156`.

Comment: @amaurymartiny just pass the found value to `expensiveFunction` again

Comment: `expensiveFunction` is expensive, I don't want to run it twice.

Comment: @amaurymartiny as far as i can think than your posted code is most optimized, let me think if i can come up with something else

Comment: @amaurymartiny just added a hacky version, you can call it a misuse of `find`, but added just out of curosity

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.reduce`, the only down side is that you can't stop once a value is found but you won't have to run `expensiveFunction` for each value.

Here is an example:

```js
const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];
const expensiveFunction = n => 2 * n;

const result = a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc) {
    const r = expensiveFunction(cur);
    if (r > 100) {
      acc = r;
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, null);



console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a smarter function for find?

```
let desiredValue;
const result = a.find( x =>{
      desiredValue = expensiveFunction(x);
      return desiredValue > 100;
});
console.log(desiredValue);
```

It will quit the expensive loop immediately after finding out the first result.

Comment: Yes but the result will be `x` not the return value of `expensiveFunction(x)`.

Comment: If you don't want to call expensive function once more, pls see update

Answer (score 3):

Here's a terse, functional version of Titus's `.reduce` answer:

```js
const arr = [2, 5, 78, 100]
const result = arr.reduce((a,v) => (a > 100 && a) || expensiveFunction(v), null)
console.log(result)
```

It iterates through the whole array, but stops executing the expensive function once the the condition is met.

Here's what I'm using personally, in case it helps anyone:

```js
const result = arr.reduce((a,v) => a || expensiveFunction(v), null)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to accept that the first matching element in your array is modified, you can do this:

```
a[a.findIndex((value, index) => {
    value = expensiveFunction(value); 
    return (value > 100 && (a[index] = value))
})] //Returns 156
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a placeholder variable to make this work - quite possibly making a for-loop the cleanest option.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping essentially runs each value through a function and returns its result as the value at that index in a new array. With this in mind, just move your `expensiveFunction` inside your `find()` method, like this:

#### Before:

```js
const result = a.map(expensiveFunction).find(x => x > 100);
```

#### After:

```js
const result = a.find(x => {
  const expensiveResult = expensiveFunction(x);
  return expensiveResult > 100;
});
```

Now it will only check the result of `expensiveFunction` for each element as the array is iterated over, and stop once the value is found.

##### A light abstraction to make things easier and more reusable

** Note, because you are not actually mapping over the array, the result of the `find()` method will be the original value at that index, not the value of `expensiveResult`.

If you want the value of `expensiveResult` to be returned and without re-running the `expensiveFunction` on the found element again needlessly, you can just move this logic into a light and reusable abstraction, like this:

```js
// Function definition

function findMap(arr, fn, condition) {
  for (const elem of arr) {
    const result = fn(elem);
    if (condition(result)) {
      return result;
    }
  }
}

// Usage

const result = findMap(a, expensiveFunction, x => x > 100);
```

##### The same light abstraction, but with no loops

…and now that same abstraction again, but this time with no loops per the original question's requirements:

```js
// Function definition

function findMap(arr, fn, condition) {
  let result;

  arr.find(x => {
    const fnResult = fn(x);
    const conditionMet = condition(fnResult);
    if (conditionMet) {
      result = fnResult;
    }
    return conditionMet;
  })

  return result;
}

// Usage (same as above)

const result = findMap(a, expensiveFunction, x => x > 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I followed is to decrease the possibility of calling the 'expensiveFunction' function to the least possible number of times. For this purpose I used the '**Divide and conquer algorithms**'. You divide the array into half parts and call the expensive function on the dividing element to decide which half to proceed. Do this step recursively until you find the smallest element above 100. Particularly for a very large sized array this method will reduce the expensive function call to a significantly smaller number. So the 'expensiveFunCaller' function will call your 'expensiveFunction' economically. The array should also be sorted first.

```
const a = [2, 5,78, 80].sort((a,b) => a-b);
const expensiveFunction = n => 2 * n;

const expensiveFunCaller= ([...arr]) =>{
  if(arr.length<2){
    let r = expensiveFunction(arr[0]);
    if(r>100) return r;
    return;
  }
  else if(arr.length === 2){
    let r = expensiveFunction(arr[0]);
    if(r>100) return r;
    r = expensiveFunction(arr[1]);
    if(r>100) return r;
    return;
  }
  let idx = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  let r = expensiveFunction(arr[idx]);

  return (r<100)?expensiveFunCaller(arr.slice(idx+1, arr.length)):expensiveFunCaller(arr.slice(0, idx+1));
}
console.log(expensiveFunCaller(a));
```

Comment: Won't work on `[2,3,78,80]`. Expected: `expensiveFunction(78)`. Actual: `expensiveFunction(80)`

Comment: @amaurymartiny I suppose he wanted to apply the function on the biggest number in the array. What special interest could he has on 78?

Comment: I want to find the **first** element in the array who value by `expensiveFunction` is > 100.

Comment: @amaurymartiny that's pretty clear now, I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple operations on an iterable, while iterating through values only once.

Below is an example of doing this, with the help of my [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, map, skipWhile} from 'iter-ops';

const a = [2, 5, 78, 4];

const res = pipe(
    a,
    map(m => 2 * m), // your expensive function
    skipWhile(r => r <= 100)
);

console.log('result:', res.first);
```

Above, it will do the same number of steps as in your `for-loop` example.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops have some interesting properties that offset the ugly-looking code with their usefulness.
The `findMap` functionality described in this question can be achieved by a simple function like this:

```js
function mapFind(array, mapFn, findFn) {
    for (const value of array) {
        const mapResult = mapFn(value);
        if (findFn(mapResult)) {
            return mapResult;
        }
    }
}

const result = mapFind([ 2, 5, 78, 4, 100 ], n => 2 * n, r => r > 100);

console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

TS version:

```js
function mapFind<T, U>(array: T[], mapFn: (value: T) => U, findFn: (value: U) => unknown): U | undefined {
    for (const value of array) {
        const mapResult = mapFn(value);
        if (findFn(mapResult)) {
            return mapResult;
        }
    }
}

const result = mapFind([ 2, 5, 78, 4, 100 ], n => 2 * n, r => r > 100);

console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can go through a shortest way by using ternary operator to simplify the condition and filter() to remove Boolean(null) values of an Array.

```js
const a = [2, 5, 78, 100];
const result  = a.map((n)=>  2*n > 100 ? 2*n : null ).filter(Boolean)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You duplicated the expensive computation, here.