# How to avoid Javascript Iterators compute before using array method in chaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, iterator, generator

1. generators/iterators allow to manipulate sequence of object without having to first build all the sequence item. Thus it can save memory space on the machine.
2. Array methods like `map`, `reduce`, `find`, `forEach`, etc. are essential in functional programming because it allows to write code as a sequence of pure function, easier to testing, etc.

I would like a fair solution that let me use generators/iterators and the array functions.

Let's have a look at this code:

```
function* myGen() {
   yield 1;
   yield 2;
   yield 3;
   throw new Error('oups');
}

const y = [...myGen()].find(x => x > 2);
assert.deepStrictEqual(y, 3);
```

This will not work **because the spreading first occurs**, taking all the memory space, and the generator function will go until its end and throw the exception.

In this example, I was hoping that Javascript would execute the code of the `find` function first, foreach element before each next iterator computation.

I would like a solution that allows me to use the array methods, without building a full array first. Is it possible in Javascript?

Comment: "*I would like a solution that allows me to use the array methods, without building a full array first.*" array methods always require a materialised collection. They aren't lazy. You can re-create them using generators but you need one for each method.

Comment: Nothing built-in, you have to rewrite array methods to be able to use them with generators. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760204/989121

Comment: Excellent your library armita. Would be good to make it esm and typescript. I am going to do a pull request.

Comment: Library [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), for one, gives you the methods you seek.